# C# WebBrowser ввод данных для получения ИНН физ.лица на сайте налоговой

Tags: c#, webbrowser

Пробую написать программу, которая бы заходила на сайт https://service.nalog.ru/inn.do, заполняла форму, и получала ИНН, если все верно заполнено. Проблема в том, что при первичном входе на сайт спрашивают, согласен ли я с обработкой персональных данных ( там чек бокс и кнопка), после этого нажатия "Согласен", сайт редиректит уже на основную страницу сервиса. После нажатия на кнопку "Согласен", выводит ошибку, что поле фамилия не найдено, но это понятно, что редирект не произошел видимо. Что я делаю не правильно?

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WebBrowser br = new WebBrowser();
        br.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted);
        br.Navigate("https://service.nalog.ru/inn.do");
        while (br.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
        {
            Application.DoEvents();
        }
        br.Document.GetElementById("personalData").SetAttribute("checked", "checked");
        HtmlElementCollection elc = br.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button");
        foreach (HtmlElement el in elc)
        {
            if (el.GetAttribute("type").Equals("button"))
            {
                el.InvokeMember("Click");
            }
        }
        while (br.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
        {
            Application.DoEvents();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Natigated to {1}");
        Console.WriteLine(br.Document.Body.InnerHtml);
        br.Document.GetElementById("fam").InnerText = "Иванов";
        br.Document.GetElementById("nam").InnerText = "Иван";
        br.Document.GetElementById("otch").InnerText = "Иванович";
        br.Document.GetElementById("bdate").InnerText = "11.11.1111";
        br.Document.GetElementById("doctype").SetAttribute("value", "21");
        br.Document.GetElementById("docno").InnerText = "00 00 000000";
        br.Document.GetElementById("btn_Send").InvokeMember("click");
        Console.WriteLine(br.Document.GetElementById("resultInn").InnerText);

        Console.WriteLine(br.Document.Body.InnerHtml);

    }
```

Comment: `Что я делаю не правильно?` - используете `WebBrowser`, который заставляет вас много чего делать лишнего, да и не факт, что вы через него что то сделаете, ибо на сайте активно используется JS (с которым `WebBrowser` очень плохо дружит). Правильным решением будет простая отправка `POST` запроса на нужный адрес с нужными данными и в ответ вам сервер выдаст результат в удобном виде (JSON), вот и все. А сейчас, ну каким то чудом вы получите через браузер данные, что дальше? Будете парсить HTML? Ну такое...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ можно Selenium попробовать. Он точно совсем справится.

Comment: @iluxa1810 Это все зависит от задачи. Как по мне, Selenium в такой ситуации, это как пулеметом по мухам стрелять, много лишнего и ненужного (от лишних библиотек, до того же ковыряния в HTML (а не в удобном JSON)), да и кода здесь всего лишь на пару строк, не более, ибо нет тут какой либо защиты, достаточно просто отправить запрос на нужный адрес, все. Так зачем же тут Selenium?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ т.е. получается, т.к. там форма отправляется через post запрос, я могу этот пост запрос сделать у себя в коде, правильно?

Comment: @AndreySherman Конечно! И этого достаточно. Вот пожалуйста, нужный [POST запрос](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epi5N.png), а вот [его ответ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ShyE.png). Зачем тут браузеры, хоть убейте, не пойму... Единственная проблема может возникнуть с капчей (тут она вроде есть), но ее не будет у вас, если вы не будете посылать уйму запросов разом.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Спасибо, все получилось.

Answer (score 1):

В общем благодаря помощи @EvgeniyZ отказался от использования WebBrowser, и написал может и плохой код, но все же рабочий. Так что если кому надо получать данные из service.nalog.ru/inn.do то вот:

```
[DataContract]
public class fns
{   
    [DataMember]
    public string inn { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public bool captchaRequired { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int code { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://service.nalog.ru/inn-proc.do");
        request.Method = "POST"; // для отправки используется метод Post
                                 // данные для отправки
        string data = "c=innMy&captcha=&captchaToken=&fam=Иванов&nam=Иван&otch=Иванович&bdate=29.08.1988&bplace=&doctype=21&docno=01+01+2000&docdt";
        // преобразуем данные в массив байтов
        byte[] byteArray = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
        // устанавливаем тип содержимого - параметр ContentType
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        // Устанавливаем заголовок Content-Length запроса - свойство ContentLength
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

        //записываем данные в поток запроса
        using (Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        }

        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                DataContractJsonSerializer deserializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(fns));

                fns res = (fns)deserializer.ReadObject(stream);
                Console.WriteLine(res.inn);
            }
        }



        response.Close();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

}