# При использовании Selenium, вставляется часть текста в поле

Tags: python, sqlite, selenium

Использую БД sqlite3, из которого беру информацию для [сайта](https://service.nalog.ru/inn.do). Но при тестировании (при повторном запуске, буквы могут быть другими) выводит не полный текст на сайте, пример:

[image: Скриншот]

---

Вот мой код:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
import sqlite3
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import UnexpectedAlertPresentException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

con = sqlite3.connect(r'F:\db\Telegram_Bot\Base.db')

base = con.execute(f"SELECT * FROM Passport").fetchall()

for result in base:
    try:
        con.execute(f"ALTER TABLE Passport ADD COLUMN INN TEXT")
    except:
        pass
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='<path-to-chrome>', options=options)
    browser.get('https://service.nalog.ru/inn.do')
    timeout = 5
    wait = WebDriverWait(browser, timeout)
    browser.find_element(By.ID, 'unichk_0').click()
    browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'btn-next').click()
    # fAMILY_1 = result[0]
    # nAME_1 = result[1]
    # fATHERNAME_1 = result[2]
    # bIRTHDAY = result[7]
    # pASSP_SERIES = result[9]
    # pASSP_NUMBER = result[10]
    # dELIVERYDATE = result[11]
    time.sleep(2)
    browser.find_element(By.NAME,'fam').send_keys(result[0])
    browser.find_element(By.NAME,'nam').send_keys(result[1])
    browser.find_element(By.NAME,'otch').send_keys(result[2])
    browser.find_element(By.NAME,'bdate').send_keys(result[7])
    time.sleep(10)
    browser.close()
```

---

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться, почему текст выводится не полный (в print выводит полный).

Comment: попробуйте дать паузу после присвоения. веб-драйвер как бы быстрее человека работает.

Comment: @nexoma
Пробовал через time.sleep(), если так то проблема осталась. пробовал сделать так - **"wait.until(browser.find_element(By.NAME,'fam').send_keys(result[0]))"**, тогда выдает ошибку - **"TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable"**, ругаясь на эту же строку.

Comment: Нашел возможный ответ **[тут](https://qna.habr.com/q/941663)**. Но мне не получается применить

Comment: тогда ActionChains https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/actions_api/keyboard/   то есть кликаем на поле, потом ActionChains шлет строку

Comment: @nexoma Попробовал, тут либо я не понимаю как это сделать (что скорее всего) либо не сработало для меня. смотрел по  ссылкам **[тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53698033/how-to-click-on-an-element-through-selenium-actionchain-and-python)** и **[в целом, перечитал всю статью](https://habr.com/ru/post/273115/)**. Кроме этого думал проблема с **[форматированием](https://question-it.com/questions/17787465/selenium-vstavte-formatirovannyj-tekst-v-veb-pole)** текста, но не получилось

Comment: поймите, что это просто клавиатура и всё. мышкой кликаете перед этим. еще раз, не торопясь, перечитать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в продолжение диалога так сказать, Action chains

вот пример, 3 комментария на русском :)

```
# import webdriver
from selenium import webdriver
  
# import Action chains 
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
  
# create webdriver object
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
  
# get geeksforgeeks.org
driver.get("https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/")
  
# get element 
element = driver.find_element_by_class_name("gsc-input")
  
# create action chain object
action = ActionChains(driver)
  
# click the item  КЛИКАЕМ МЫШКОЙ НА ПОЛЕ ВВОДА
action.click(on_element = element)
  
# send keys С КЛАВИАТУРЫ ШЛЕМ СИМВОЛЫ СТРОКИ
action.send_keys("Arrays")
  
# perform the operation ЭТО ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО, 
#ЗАПУСК ЦЕПОЧКИ АКЦИЙ   :) не АЦЦЦКИ

action.perform()
```

пример отсюда https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/send_keys-method-action-chains-in-selenium-python/

что в вашем случае будет так

```
action = ActionChains(driver)
### browser.find_element(By.NAME,'fam').send_keys(result[0])
action.click(on_element = browser.find_element(By.NAME,'fam'))
action.send_keys(result[0])
### ... остальные поля
action.perform()
```

прим., есть еще способ

```
driver.execute_script(f"document.getElementsByName('lfam').value={result[0]}")
```

---

upd.

так как на налог.ру стоят javascipt-ы от яндекса, блокирующие стандартные методы ввода, то тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50139506/how-can-you-reduce-the-speed-of-entering-characters-selenium-python  предложено следующее, посимвольный ввод:

```
import time

def send_delayed_keys(element, text, delay=0.3) :
    for c in text :
        endtime = time.time() + delay
        element.send_keys(c)
        time.sleep(endtime - time.time())
```

и при вызове:

```
send_delayed_keys(browser.find_element(By.NAME,'nam'), "АБВГДЕЁЖЗИКЛМНОПРСТУФ", 0.2)
```

он медленно, но аккуратно, всё-таки заполняет поле

Comment: Спасибо большое что объяснили, действительно не правильно делал, но все равно заполняет поле коряво... Советовали попробовать JavaScript через selenium. Сейчас ищу как это сделать.

Comment: так это в последней строке ответа посмотрите. вы можете perform ставить после каждой операции и паузы ставьте

Comment: мистика, попробовал уже сам, и в chrome, и в firefox

Comment: гениальный подход! https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1024939/c-webbrowser-%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%98%D0%9D%D0%9D-%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9?ysclid=lfa3hwetyj743566399  посылать сразу POST-запрос

Comment: Извините меня пожалуйста... я слепой идиот))))) видел только про **ActionChains**, а **def send_delayed_keys** не увидел. Спасибо огромное, все получилось!!!)))

Comment: принимайте ответ. завершайте вопрос. успехов. хорошая была задачка.

Answer (score 1):

Благодаря ответу @nexoma. Дальше была проблема с полем - Серия и номер документа. Решил тем же способом, но немного изменил. Вот код (может быть коряво... но ведь работает :-) ):

```html
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
import sqlite3
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import UnexpectedAlertPresentException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

con = sqlite3.connect(r'F:\db\Telegram_Bot\Base.db')

base = con.execute(f"SELECT * FROM Passport").fetchall()


def send_delayed_keys(element, text, delay=0.1) :
        for c in text:
            endtime = time.time() + delay
            element.send_keys(c)
            time.sleep(endtime - time.time())

def send_delayed_keys_number(element, text, delay=0.1) :
        for c in str(abs(text)):
            endtime = time.time() + delay
            element.send_keys(c)
            time.sleep(endtime - time.time())

for result in base:
    
    try:
        con.execute(f"ALTER TABLE Passport ADD COLUMN INN TEXT")
    except:
        pass
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='<path-to-chrome>', options=options)
    browser.get('https://service.nalog.ru/inn.do')
    browser.find_element(By.ID, 'unichk_0').click()
    browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'btn-next').click()
    fAMILY_1 = result[0]
    
    nAME_1 = result[1]
    fATHERNAME_1 = result[2]
    bIRTHDAY = result[7]
    pASSP = int(str(result[9]) + str(result[10]))
    dELIVERYDATE = result[11]
    time.sleep(2)
    send_delayed_keys(browser.find_element(By.NAME,'fam'), fAMILY_1, 0.1)
    send_delayed_keys(browser.find_element(By.NAME,'nam'), nAME_1, 0.1)
    send_delayed_keys(browser.find_element(By.NAME,'otch'), fATHERNAME_1, 0.1)
    browser.find_element(By.NAME,'bdate').send_keys(bIRTHDAY)
    if len(str(pASSP)) == 10:
        send_delayed_keys_number(browser.find_element(By.NAME,'docno'), pASSP , 0.1)
    else:
         pass
    browser.find_element(By.NAME,'docdt').send_keys(dELIVERYDATE)
    browser.find_element(By.ID,  'btn_send' ).click()
    time.sleep(10)
    browser.close()
```