# Python SELENIUM не могу ввести данные! Проблема с нажатием кнопки силениум

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

Ребята перечитал фул документацию про Селениум и не могу понять в чем ошибка панчарм не ругаеться и вроде все норм но не работает.
Возможно проблема с моим установленным драйвером гугл? Просто у меня лично стоит самая новая версия 114.0.5735.110, а я установил версию 114.0.5735.90 лично не знаю влияет ли это как-то на мой программу. И вообщем вообщем ничего не работает сам нажимать на кнопки могу но программа сама ничего не вводит хотя вроде написал правильно

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument('user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 OPR/99.0.0.0')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=option)

url = 'https://vk.com'

try:
    driver.get(url=url)
    time.sleep(5)

    email_input = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "login")
    email_input.clear()
    email_input.send_keys("79433422")
    time.sleep(3)

except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)
finally:
    driver.close()
    driver.quit()
```

Вот еще код с пробой нажатия на кнопку войти:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

url = 'https://vk.com'

try:
    driver.get(url=url)
    time.sleep(5)

    email_input = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "login")
    email_input.clear()
    email_input.send_keys("79433422")
    time.sleep(3)

    login_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[contains(@class, 'FlatButton__content') and text()='Войти']")
    login_button.click()

except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)
finally:
    driver.close()
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: поизучайте тут, кратко, может стоять защита от автоматического ввода https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1504890/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-selenium-%d0%b2%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5/1505123#1505123

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В твоём коде у драйвера не указан путь. Я использовал `webdriver-manager`. Если ты хочешь использовать локальный `chromedriver`, то необходимо прописать путь к нему следующим образом:

```
 driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=твой путь)
```

Ниже приведу код, который успешно отработал с твоего примера:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=option)

url = 'https://vk.com'

try:
    driver.get(url=url)
    time.sleep(5)

    email_input = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='index_email']")
    email_input.clear()
    email_input.send_keys("79433422")
    time.sleep(3)

    login_button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[type='submit'] span[class='FlatButton__in']")
    login_button.click()
    print("Test passed: click on button ")
    time.sleep(3)

    assert_value = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,".vkuiFormItem__bottom.vkuiCaption.vkuiCaption--l-1").text
    assert assert_value == "Incorrect phone number [1000]"
    print("Test assert: Сверяет значение ошибки на странице" )

except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)
finally:
    driver.close()
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: Спасибо большое дружище!